# Discord API embed icons in text message

Tags: python, api, bots, discord

I'm currently writing on a discord bot in python. 
I got the following line:

```
data.add_field(name=piece, value=iconurl + " " + msg, inline=False)
```

Where data is my embed object, iconurl is the icon url, and msg is a String containing the text. I want it to display the image as a icon following the text in discord, but it currently only display the full URL followed by the String. Any ideas how I can display the image/icon?

Current output looks like this: 
[output in discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HY0H.png)

Answer (score 0):

Embedding has two imaging options: set_image or set_thumbnail. set_thumbnail is basically a scaled down picture, while set_image is the regular picture. Both take URLs